# Representation of Java Collections in UML2

Tags: java, collections, uml

Is there a standard representation for typed java collections in UML2? I am working on a class diagram and would like to avoid Java syntax, when using something like Map as type for a class attribute.

```
- foo : Map<Integer, String>
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192606/how-to-describe-a-contained-map-in-uml-class-diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UML2 has [parameterized classes](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Parameterized+Class/), and the syntax is in fact pretty much the same as Java's - both Java and the UML spec were inspired by the C++ syntax here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm against using too much design documents to program. Documents are only for communicating ideas, IMHO.

So if you need Java Types for your UML chances are:

- you are reverse engineering: then Java Syntax will be fine
- you are trying to program trhough UML: don't do it. Program in Java. Use UML only for object relation and collaboration

  - if the types are primitive: it's likely you don't need to express internal data structures in UML. You only need to express what's the responsibility of the class.
  - if the types are objects: ok, maybe it's the point... I'm not sure, but try to use the minimum...