# How to represent a .NET dictionary type in UML?

Tags: c#, dictionary, uml

I'm creating a uml class diagram and I would like to know if anyone can assist me with this. I would like to know how to represent a dictionary type using UML notation.
for example how can I represent the following dictionary(`Dictionary<FileType,StorageType>`)type in UML.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to ask. Are you trying to represent a member of type `Dictionary<FileType,StorageType>` inside a class?

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as a duplicate but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192606/how-to-describe-a-contained-map-in-uml-class-diagram

Answer (score 3):

I used to represent it with a [qualified association](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Qualified+Associations/)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what information you are trying to convey in your diagram.  However you could:

1. Attach a stereotype to your relationship
2. Use an association class
3. Use a Ternary association
4. Decide the collection type is an implementation detail and not show it
5. Discover some additional behaviours about the association and promote