# How to represent indexed or parametrized attributes in UML?

Tags: c#, java, parameters, uml, indexer

How to represent indexed or parametrized attributes in UML?

For example, how to reverse the following `Java` code:

```
 class MyClass {

       Object getValue(String key);
       void setValue(String key, Object value);

 }
```

From the one hand I can describe it simple

[image]

but this will not show that these 2 methods are related.

From the other hand I can describe it

[image]

but this will hide the fact, that multiple instances of a value are named by key parameter.

The similar problem arise with the following `C#` code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also elaborate about indexed or parametrized attributes? for example in Java example, do you want to represent getValue/setValue method with parameters in UML or something else ?

Comment: yes wish to express this in UML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a great answer for this since this class is in effect a dictionary/hash.  A discussion of options you can choose be found here:

[How to represent a .NET dictionary type in UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689672/how-to-represent-a-net-dictionary-type-in-uml)
or possibly this (as referenced):
[How to describe a contained map in UML class diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192606/how-to-describe-a-contained-map-in-uml-class-diagram)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you are now concerned with instances of your class (an instance for each key/value).  Instances are prefixed w/a colon.  To use your example they could look like MyClass:MyInstance

Comment: Why instances? These are classes. I want to describe a relation one-to-many.