# Is it possible to model a map cleanly in BoUML?

Tags: uml

Consider an example 11.37 of the qualified association provided in clause 11.5.5 of [UML Specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/):

[image]

It follows from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611802/5674719) and the link provided therein that this model should be implemented as a map. But when I try to do it in BoUML:

[image]

the system generates code for `Bank` which is not syntactically correct:

```
class Bank {
  private:
    map<Person *> accounts_;
};
```

Suppose I want to produce something like that:

```
class Bank {
  private:
    map<AccountNo, Person *> accounts_;
};
```

As a workaround I could, say,  use `${association}` and modify the declaration

```
${comment}${static}${thread_local}${mutable}${volatile}${const}${stereotype}<${association}, ${type} *> ${name}${value};
```

but this is wrong - `AccountNo` is not an AssociationClass.

Roundtrip does not produce a suitable model too.

Is there a clean way to implement 11.37?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this is wrong - AccountNo is not an AssociationClass.

I agree for *AccountNo* (just a number), but a bank account is not only a number, it has a name, open date, may be end date, may be interest formula, etc

So to have Account as a relation-class is the right way for me.

Else using only an account number do not use a relation-class and do not define that *typedef*, just use a relation between Bank and Person stereotyped *map* and modify its default definition to have :

`${comment}${static}${thread_local}${mutable}${volatile}${const}${stereotype}<int, ${type} *> ${name}${value};`

supposing the bank account is an `int`

If you really want to indicate the key is an `int` you can use an other stereotype indicating that (and configure how to translate that stereotype in C++, or replace `${stereotype}` by `int`), or of course use a note in the diagram